# Struts and JSF Integration

Tags: jsf, primefaces, struts2

I'm trying to create a struts project (CRUD). I refer to this link https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-crud-example-1.html
I'd like to integrate JSF to my project and so Primefaces.
After googling, I found that all the examples are created using jsp files to display the form elements.
This [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EqCS.gif) is presenting the composition of my project.
So, I have a question: Can I made `xhtml` page instead of `jsp` page? .

Comment: Why do you want / need to integrate them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, I'd like to use primefaces on xhtml pages instead of jsp pages in order to improve the style of the page.

Comment: So, you don't need Struts? In that case just follow http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jsf/916/introduction-to-jsf/3097/hello-world#t=201608191252237215624

Comment: Ok Sir, but my first and main purpose is to build a struts project, then in order to improve the view I 'd like to integrate JSF and so primefaces on xhtml page not jsp page. Could you tell me if it's possible to create Struts project like the example above but instead of index.jsp and register.jsp, I made index.xhtml and register.xhtml. then integrating jsf.Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can combine them, but that would be very weird. You effectively do not have a Struts project anymore but  a mixed one. If you want the look and feel of the PrimeFaces components but really need to use struts, then see if PrimeUI is usable (plain javascript components)

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/docs/jsf-plugin.html

Comment: @RomanC: that is an article of which I cannot see the publication date, but it hase a reference to a 9 (nine) year old article.

Comment: @Kukeltje Really I don't care what's the article and how old is it, you should check yourself if it works for you or not. Sometimes it occurs that things work for on man and doesn't work for another :(-

Answer (score 3):

You seem to think that JSF is similar to taglibs or template libraries - some library that only lives in the presentation layer. **It is not so**. JSF is a single framework replacing both *View* and *Controller* layers known from other frameworks. The integration is so complete (basically, each on-page component contains its own view and its own controller) that those two aspects are unseparable. You cannot just take the view layer from JSF without the controller part. And the controller part requires that JSF has full control over HTTP request.

If you were a real expert on both Struts and JSF, and were actually forced to do it, you could attempt to write code processing a single request with both Struts and JSF frameworks. But there is absolutely nothing to be gained. You would just end up with two paralell ways of doing everything.